# Align lists like coreutils' `ls`

Tags: code-golf

Make program that takes the list from the files from STDIN, and aligns it nicely, just like `ls` command from coreutils. For example, assuming the following list (taken [from The ASCII Collab](https://github.com/OddLlama/ascii-gallows-club/blob/master/wordlists/animals.txt), which takes place in the chatroom on this site).

```
alligator
ant
bear
bee
bird
camel
cat
cheetah
chicken
chimpanzee
cow
crocodile
deer
dog
dolphin
duck
eagle
elephant
fish
fly
fox
frog
giraffe
goat
goldfish
hamster
hippopotamus
horse
kangaroo
kitten
leopard
lion
lizard
llama
lobster
monkey
octopus
ostrich
otter
owl
oyster
panda
parrot
pelican
pig
pigeon
porcupine
puppy
rabbit
rat
reindeer
rhinoceros
rooster
scorpion
seal
shark
sheep
shrimp
snail
snake
sparrow
spider
squid
squirrel
swallow
swan
tiger
toad
tortoise
turtle
vulture
walrus
weasel
whale
wolf
zebra
```

Align the results, like the in the example below (the example shows columns set to 80). The terminal width is received as the first argument. If any argument is bigger than this argument, you can do anything. Try to use as many columns as possible with two space separators, as long nothing overflows.

```
alligator   crocodile  giraffe       llama    pig         shark     tiger
ant         deer       goat          lobster  pigeon      sheep     toad
bear        dog        goldfish      monkey   porcupine   shrimp    tortoise
bee         dolphin    hamster       octopus  puppy       snail     turtle
bird        duck       hippopotamus  ostrich  rabbit      snake     vulture
camel       eagle      horse         otter    rat         sparrow   walrus
cat         elephant   kangaroo      owl      reindeer    spider    weasel
cheetah     fish       kitten        oyster   rhinoceros  squid     whale
chicken     fly        leopard       panda    rooster     squirrel  wolf
chimpanzee  fox        lion          parrot   scorpion    swallow   zebra
cow         frog       lizard        pelican  seal        swan
```

Comment: Is the width of a column always 2 more than the biggest word in the column?

Comment: @Cruncher: Yes, this is how `ls` outputs it.

Comment: You're right about `ls` but "as many columns as possible" suggests just a single space between columns.

Comment: @DarrenStone: It does? Well then, I modified the question to explicitly mention the 2 space separators then.

Comment: Further to this, your example output is not what `ls` would produce since the column with "ostrich" is narrower than the column with "hippopotamus". On my system, `ls` generates equal width columns.  You might remove the phrase "just like ls command" to reduce confusion.

Comment: @DarrenStone: This is mistake on my part. This was output for 70, not 80. Also, this is output from coreutils' ls - it may be different in other implementations.

Comment: I checked FreeBSD's ls for fun. It appears to make equal width columns, which probably simpler to make.

Comment: You may miss my point. You ask for output "just like ls command", which means equal width columns. You also ask for output with "as many columns as possible", which means columns of varying widths as your example shows.  I think variable width columns are much more interesting to code but it may be too late since people are submitting answers.

Comment: @xfix Your example output is 76 characters wide - which is clearly more than 70.

Comment: @Howard: Oh, right. This was my mistake. Anyway, I created some files, and made a screenshot - http://i.stack.imgur.com/g2dzH.png.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Bash, <s>48</s> 46 bytes

```
cd `mktemp -d`
xargs -d\\n tee
stty cols $1
ls
```

Guaranteed to work like *ls*.

Comment: This fails if one of the items contains whitespace. It should be `>"$R"`.

Comment: I could swear I read "words" somewhere in the question. Oh, well...

Comment: Newest edit uses ls in the answer...

Comment: @Shingetsu: All revisions use *ls*.

Comment: Shouldn't using ls to emulate ls be banned?
I mean I get the idea, but it just seems wrong.

Comment: @Shingetsu: I agree that using *ls* to make something "look like *ls*" is a little bold, but since *ls* is used in an entirely different manner, I though it would be OK. Now, if the question asked for a program to list a directory's contents and format the output like *ls*, that would be different...

Comment: @Shingetsu: I actually expected this to happen (in fact, my test solution which was used to make an example) was using `ls` directly.

Comment: @xfix what's amusing is they could legitly read the source for GNU ls and just obfuscate it...
Of course they'd need to add the GPL clause, but hey~

Answer (score 4):

#### GolfScript, 79 characters

```
n%:I{)I/{{,}$-1=,}:L%{2++}*"#{ARGV[0]}"~)<}I,,?)/{.L{:x' '*+x<}+%}%zip{'  '*n}/
```

Assumes a two spaces between the columns (although it can be changed easily to one which saves 2 characters).

Comment: How is the input entered if one wants to test it? :)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson As specified in the question - console width as first argument and list of names on STDIN.

Comment: Tested with 30 columns and getting a rather peculiar result :)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Thank you - that was simply a bug in the implementation. Fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

**Python 3 (394)**

Feels longish, but works and isn't *horrible* to read;

```py
import sys,math
f=sys.stdin.read().splitlines()
l,w=len(f),int(sys.argv[1])
for y in range(w,0,-1):
 n=math.ceil(l/y)
 r=[f[i:l:n]for i in range(0,n)]
 c=[max(len(s[i]) if i<len(s) else 0 for s in r) for i in range(y)]
 if sum(c)+len(c)*2-2<=w:break
for i in range(len(r)):
 s=len(r[i])
 for j in range(s):
  t=r[i][j]
  sys.stdout.write(t+(' '*(c[j]-len(t)+2) if j<s-1 else '\n'))
```

Basically it tries with fewer and fewer columns until they all fit. It will always output at least one column even if the file names won't fit the width.

Answer (score 0):

## BASH, <strike>13</strike> 15

```
column -s"\n"-c
```

You can append the column width argument like this:

```
column -s"\n"-c80
```

Reads text from STDIN and aligns it in columns.

Comment: This gives me tab separated columns. I'm not quite sure why it happens (man page for column says that the default is two spaces), but it does (at least for me).

Comment: Right, i just noticed that as well. Wasn't meant as a serious submission anyway.

Answer (score 0):

### C++11, 409 bytes

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;main(int i,char*a[]){int w=atoi(a[1]),n,c,x,r;int v[w];vector<string>l;string s;while(getline(cin,s))l.push_back(s);n=l.size();for(c=n;c>1;--c){r=n/c+(n%c!=0);for(i=0;i<n;++i)v[i/r]=max((int)l[i].size(),i%r?v[i/r]:0);for(i=x=0;i<c;++i)x+=v[i]+=i<c-1?2:0;if(x<=w)break;}for(i=0;i<n;++i)printf(((i+1)%c&&i<n-1)?"%1$-*2$s":"%s\n",l[i*r%n].c_str(),v[i%c]);}
```

Below is the slightly non-golfed version. If I may point you at something potentially interesting, then please take a look at the silly format strings of the last printf.

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
main(int i,char*a[]){
int w=atoi(a[1]),n,c,x,r;
int v[w];
vector<string>l;string s;while(getline(cin,s))l.push_back(s);n=l.size();
for(c=n;c>1;--c){
 r=n/c+(n%c!=0);
 for(i=0;i<n;++i)v[i/r]=max((int)l[i].size(),i%r?v[i/r]:0);
 for(i=x=0;i<c;++i)x+=v[i]+=i<c-1?2:0;
 if(x<=w)break;
}
for(i=0;i<n;++i)
 printf(((i+1)%c&&i<n-1)?"%1$-*2$s":"%s\n",l[i*r%n].c_str(),v[i%c]);
}
```

Comment: You don't have to declare int main parameters, or name them like that. `argv` is just a convention.

Comment: @xfix, thank you for the tip, I renamed argc and argv. However, plain argc without the "int" gives an error on my g++, which is why I had left the "int" there.

Comment: Come to think of it, if I am stuck with argc, I might it use it for something. Replaced 'i' with it. Now at 409 bytes; not so far from the python solution. :)